# How we can specify nl2br() for 1 row when everything goes to array

Tags: php, json

So on database we have 20 rows, 1 of them look like that:

1) cool text

2) not rly

3) something else?

Rest of the rows are 1 line data

So if we need to output a single row with line break we use `nl2br($row['name'])`
But what if we have to create a json data from our table?
For creating json data we do a few loops and generete data like that :

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($topic == 'Some'){
  $data= array_merge($data,$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}
if($topic == 'Something else'){
  $data2= array_merge($data2,$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}
$outp = array('First Line'=>$data, 'Secound Line'=>$data2);
$myJSON = json_encode($outp, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $myJSON;
```

how to insert nl2br without giving 20 lines of code extra? can it be something like `$row['name']= nl2br($row['name'])` just before fetch data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop after you fetch all the rows:

```
foreach ($data as &$row) {
    $row['name'] = nl2br($row['name']);
}
```